# dplyr joining column not appearing

Tags: r, dplyr

I have these 2 data frames:

```
library(dplyr)
x =data.frame(ID = c("1-9","8-9","d"), col=c("A","B","h"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
y = data.frame(ID = c("2-9","4-9","5-9","1-9","8-9"), g=c(letters[1:5]), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I'd like to join so that the result is

```
ID  col  ID.y   g
1-9  A   1-9    D
8-9  B   8-9    E
d    h   NA     NA
```

How can that be done?

```
x %>% dplyr::left_join( y, by=c("ID"="ID"),suffix = c(".x", ".y"))

x %>% left_join( y, by = "ID", copy = FALSE, 
           suffix = c(".x", ".y"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dplyr` will not duplicate the join column when joining tables, and the suffix is only applied to columns that have the same names in each table that are not used in the join.

To get what you're looking for, you will need to replicate the ID field in one table, and then join after that:

```
y$ID.y <- y$ID
dplyr::left_join(x,y, by="ID")

#Output
#   ID col    g ID.y
#1 1-9   A    d  1-9
#2 8-9   B    e  8-9
#3   d   h <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: but why didn' t the g column appear? it was in the y table

Comment: the `g` column appears when I run the code above, and is shown in the output. Do you want to re-order the columns? Is that what you're asking for?

Comment: no in the original post the g column did not appear

Comment: hmm...Not sure. It also appeared for me in the output of the code you provided. Only `ID.y` was missing from what I was seeing.